# Managing and Redeploying Scheduled Tasks at Runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jvm, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for a solution / architecture to achieve the following:

- A Java application (Spring Boot on an embedded Tomcat) makes use of various scheduled tasks (e.g. by using Spring's `@Scheduled` or tools like Quartz Scheduler).
- I want to be able to add/remove, start/stop and update scheduled tasks without stopping the main application or interfering with the other tasks.

I found references to programmatically start/stop/retime a task, but am I right that there wouldn't be a way to update the code for some tasks without afterwards restarting the entire application?

**Constraints**

- I would like to reuse existing app code, so implementing the tasks in another language and executing them by any other means (e.g. cronjobs) is not preferred.
- I can't afford to let each task run as a separate application in its own virtual machine (because of available RAM).

One option I could think of is to split the app, so that the main application is the Spring Boot App on the embedded Tomcat. Each scheduled task then becomes its own app built as a WAR and deployed to one shared application container. I assume that in this case all tasks would share a JVM while being manageable/deployable individually. I imagine the downside would be a more sophisticated build-process, dependencies to shared-app-code that might make it necessary to redeploy some/all of the tasks if the app code changes, more complicated integration testing, and a bit of overhead to operating each of those as separate WARs.

Is that a sane solution? What other, better options are there? Do one of the  tools (the JVM, Spring, Quartz, ...) have something built in that I am missing?

Comment: Each scheduled task in it's own WAR sounds like a good solution. The same is used in one of the companies I know... Although at that point of time I thought it is antiquated, they were able to build a UI to start/stop/remove those jobs/wars in a hot manner... :-)

Comment: Cannot you use an existing Quartz scheduler manager with a GUI that can remotely connect to your Quartz instance and that allows you to manage jobs and triggers? To pause (stop) a particular Quartz job, all you need to do is to pause all job's triggers. The resume operation works similarly. As far as I know there are two Quartz management tools - MySchedule (discontinued few years ago, but still available for download; free), QuartzDesk (paid, trial licenses + online demo available, lots of features not available elsewhere). Disclaimer: I am in the QuartzDesk team.